# Numerical Methods for Solving a Fully Nonlinear Time-Dependent PDE?

Tags: pde, nonlinear-equations, reference-request, time-integration

Are there numerical methods of solving the following fully nonlinear time-dependent PDE:
$$\nabla^2u\left(\textbf{r}(t), \dot{r}(t), t\right)=f\left(\textbf{r}(t), \dot{r}(t), t\right),$$
for $\textbf{r}(t)$, where $\nabla^2 = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 x}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 y}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 z}$ and $\mathbf{r}(t)=x(t)\mathbf{i}+y(t)\mathbf{j}+z(t)\mathbf{k}$?

Could FACR (Fourier Analysis Cyclic Reduction) be used to solve this?

Also, could you recommend a reference that would help me numerically solve this or a similar problem?

<sup>thanks</sup>

Comment: Note that with an iterative method, it can be beneficial to solve for the difference $f(t_2) - f(t_1)$ to go forward in time

Comment: @ChristianClason I've clarified: I'm interested in when $u(t)$ is a function containing time-derivatives. thanks

Comment: @ChristianClason Thanks for the welcome. I didn't know this SE existed until today. I'm not sure why it's called computational science, though, which makes me think of cs.SE, and not something like "numerical methods".SE.

Comment: @Geremia where is the time derivatives in the PDE equation?

Comment: @Geremia Both "computational science" and "scientific computing" have become standard terms for the application of computational methods in the physical (and biological, and engineering, and ...) sciences. (There's a slight difference, if you care to make one, but it doesn't really matter here.) It's definitely not computer science, but it's also not (just) numerical mathematics.

Comment: @ChristianClason I've added some more detail. I hope it helps clarify my question.

Comment: @ChristianClason Interesting. Thanks for the terminological clarification. It appears there's more than _NR in C_. ☺

Comment: @Geremia Thank you for making the edit. Could you please also make explicit with respect to which variables the partial derivatives are taken (i.e., is $\nabla^2 u(x,y,z) = d^2/dx^2 u(x,y,z)$ or $d^2/dy^2 u(x,y,z)$ or $d^2/dx^2 u(x,y,z)+d^2/dz^2 u(x,y,z)$ or ...)? In fact, it would be best to avoid this misunderstandable shorthand notation and just write the derivatives explicitly.

Comment: @ChristianClason I've clarified: $\nabla^2 = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 x}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 y}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 z}$. In other words: No partial derivatives with respect to time appear anywhere.

Comment: @Geremia Thanks; I've edited a bit to make it even clearer (IMO). I've also taken the liberty of changing the title, because the "Poisson" equation is really misleading -- it's just a nonlinear PDE. I'm not sure how much can be said without specifying $u$ (and if you do, you can just compute the derivatives of $u$ explicitly and *then* insert $x(t)$ for $x$, $\dot x(t)$ for y $and $t$ for $z$, so you'd end up with a specific nonlinear PDE. It would really help if you gave some background on the problem you're actually trying to solve; I doubt you'd get useful answer to such a general question.

Comment: @ChristianClason Yes, that's a good edit, but I think just writing what the operator $\nabla^2$ in this case is, instead of showing it acting on $u(x,y,z)$, might be clearer. Perhaps you don't like my writing $u$ and $f$ is functionals?

Comment: @Geremia, It's not, since I seem to have interpreted it incorrectly! I really have a hard time understanding the actual equation you're trying to solve, because it's still not clear what the derivative is taken with respect to. Could you give an explicit example for a simple $u$? And you would do me a favor if you used the following notation: $r(t,x)$, where $t$ is the time coordinate, $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is the space coordinate, and for every $(t,x)$, $r(t,x) = (r_1(t,x),r_2(t,x),r_3(t,x))$. And for $u$, write $u(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ (such that in your first equation, you set $z_1 = r(t,x)$ etc.)

Comment: In any case, the answer to your question is a resounding "No, FACR cannot be used, since that is a specific (multigrid) method for solving the linear systems arising from the *linear* Poisson equation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep things simple, we will approximate $\nabla^2u(\textbf{x},\dot{\textbf{x}},t)$ with some operator $L[u(\textbf{x},\dot{\textbf{x}},t)]$ that uses finite difference approximations:

$$ \nabla^2u(\textbf{x},\dot{\textbf{x}},t) \approx L[u(\textbf{x},\dot{\textbf{x}},t)] = \sum_{k=1}^{d} \frac{u(\textbf{x}-h\hat{\textbf{e}}_k,\dot{\textbf{x}},t) - 2u(\textbf{x},\dot{\textbf{x}},t) + u(\textbf{x}+h\hat{\textbf{e}}_k,\dot{\textbf{x}},t)}{h^2}   $$

where $d$ is the dimension of $\textbf{x}$, $h \ll 1$, and $\hat{\textbf{e}}_k$ is the unit vector in the $k^{th}$ direction. Based on this approximation, we can then view the solution to this problem as finding a path based on the constraining "dynamics" you have listed. This can then be viewed from the perspective of Calculus of Variations, where we wish to find an optimal path. This allows us to specify a cost function to minimize, such as:

$$J[\textbf{x}] = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\left( L[u(\textbf{x},\dot{\textbf{x}},t)] - f(\textbf{x},\dot{\textbf{x}},t)\right)^2 dt$$

where $t_1$ and $t_2$ bound the time frame you care about, and your optimal path $\textbf{x}$ will minimize the cost. To make this path more easily approximated, let's approximate $\textbf{x}(t)$ by some basis, expressed as the following:

$$ \textbf{x}_{h}(t) = \sum_{j}^{n} \textbf{a}_{j} \phi_{j}(t)$$
$$ \dot{\textbf{x}}_{h}(t) = \sum_{j}^{n} \textbf{a}_{j} \dot{\phi}_{j}(t)$$

By using this approximation, $\textbf{x}_{h}(t)$, in place of $\textbf{x}(t)$, the problem can be tackled by finding the coefficients $\textbf{a}_j$ such that the cost function is minimized. This optimization looks like it will be ugly, but this is at least one way you might go about solving it.

Comment: interesting. I've re-edited my question to making $u\left(\vec{r}(t), t\right)$ any function involving the first derivative of $\left|\vec{r}(t)\right|$. I'm interested in a general solution to such a "time-dependent Poisson equation" (if it can even be called a Poisson equation).

Comment: @Geremia so you mean you're looking for a general approach to solving this problem numerically, correct? Because when I hear the term "general solution", I think closed form (which could be ideal but I think is unlikely).

Comment: Yes, I want a numerical solution, not a "closed-form" one.

Comment: @Geremia well I believe this is at least one approach you can take to solve this problem in a general sense.